# What is the font used in Capital in the SunWise Capital logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

[image: SunWise image]

Does anybody know what that elongated sans-serif font is used for the word **CAPITAL**? I'm sure I've used it before I just can't remember what it was. Any help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: It does look like Eurostile, however this website is a great tool if you ever get stuck. You just post a screenshot or image and it scans the letters for a match! http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word CAPITAL is probably written using font 'Eurostile'

[image]

Comment: Eurostile Extended, to be specific

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! :) I used Eurostile. Just resized it so it would look squished vertically. I was in a hurry doing that project and there was no one who was answering this post but thank you so much for all of your efforts! :)